# MassTransit consumer consume context filtering with dependency support

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, masstransit

I've been researching a bit on implementing an authorization middle-ware to authorize incoming messages on a consumer level (not message-level).
Here's a simplified version of such filter:

```
public class ConsumerAuthorizationFilter<TConsumer> : IFilter<ConsumerConsumeContext<TConsumer>>
    where TConsumer : class
{
    private readonly IAuthorizationService _authorizationService;

    public ConsumerAuthorizationFilter(IAuthorizationService authorizationService)
    {
        _authorizationService = authorizationService;
    }

    public async Task Send(ConsumerConsumeContext<TConsumer> context, IPipe<ConsumerConsumeContext<TConsumer>> next)
    {
        // some authorization magic using _authorizationService;
    }
```

In the DI, under the receive endpoint, AFAIK, something like the following needs to be done:

```
receiveEndpointConfigurator.Consumer<SomeConsumer>(busRegistrationContext, x =>
                x.UseFilter(new ConsumerAuthorizationFilter<SomeConsumer>(new _____)));
```

However, as I'm still on the configuration phase of the application, I do not have access to the IServiceProvider, hence no access to the AuthorizationService.

How can I achieve my goal here?

Thanks.

P.S. On filter examples I've seen with DI support, the filters are not consumer-based, rather message-based, and the concrete filters are not needed at the configuration phase, and are created at run time.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved to getting the service directly from the service provider at the Send() context and not on ctor.

```
IServiceScope serviceScope = context.GetPayload<IServiceScope>();
serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IAuthorizationService>();
```